# Библиотека для склонения по падежам

Tags: c#, .net

На просторах интернета пруд пруди онлайн-сервисов, но хочется чего-нибудь автономного.

Есть ли для .NET, хорошая и бесплатная библиотека, которая способна просклонять по падежам текст?

Нашел вот [такую](https://github.com/petrovich/petrovich-net), но почему-то она не работает ругаясь исключение TypeLoadException...

Comment: Есть ещё известная padeg.dll, но она вроде не dotNet

Comment: https://github.com/mikhail-barg/petrovich-net-lite